# In the `maintenance_tasks` gem, how do we set `limit`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When `collection` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, how do we set `limit` for each "batch"?  `job-iteration`'s [Best Practices](https://github.com/Shopify/job-iteration/blob/1ebc6974cceddd7e526630e85875059cf6c9da0f/guides/best-practices.md#batch-iteration) says it defaults to 100.  100 is way too small for expensive queries and/or large datasets.

It looks like that's passed in [here](https://github.com/Shopify/job-iteration/blob/1ebc6974cceddd7e526630e85875059cf6c9da0f/lib/job-iteration/active_record_enumerator.rb#L10-L12).

But when using the `maintenance_tasks` gem, in the `collection` method, we're not explicitly building an enumerator. So how can we pass in or set the `@batch_size`?  I've tried some guesses like `@batch_size`, `@of`, `def batch_size`, `def of` inside the `MaintenanceTasks::Task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considered a missing API in the gem and a PR is welcome.

https://github.com/Shopify/maintenance_tasks/issues/890

Answer (score 0):

The `maintenance_tasks` gem does not provide a way to directly set the @batch_size instance variable. However, you can control the batch size using the `find_each` method with the `:batch_size` option in the collection method.

If you want to set a different batch size for each task, you should use the `find_each` method with the `:batch_size` option in the collection method of each task. The `find_each` method returns an `Enumerator` that yields batches of records, which is what the `maintenance_tasks` gem expects.

Note that the `find_each` method is part of `ActiveRecord`, and its functionality is not directly related to the `maintenance_tasks` gem. It's used to fetch records in batches from the database, which can improve performance when dealing with large datasets.

Here is an example of how to set a batch size in the collection method:

```
module Maintenance
class UpdatePostsThrottledTask < MaintenanceTasks::Task
  throttle_on(backoff: 1.minute) do
    DatabaseStatus.unhealthy?
  end

  def collection
    Post.find_each(batch_size: 1000)
  end

  def process(post)
    post.update!(content: "New content added on #{Time.now.utc}")
  end
end
```

end

Comment: `#collection` can't be an `Enumerator` (it gives the error "#collection must be either an Active Record Relation, ActiveRecord::Batches::BatchEnumerator, Array, or CSV.").  
  
`#in_batches(batch_size: 2000)` works (it returns an `ActiveRecord::Batches::BatchEnumerator`), but I don't want to [process a batch](https://github.com/Shopify/maintenance_tasks/tree/main#processing-batch-collections) in `process`, I want to process individual items.

`#in_batches(batch_size: 2000).each_record` also returns an `Enumerator`.